# Enviar formulario sem aparecer o alerta do navegador

Tags: javascript, redirect

Estou submetendo um formulário com *JS* e depois de dar tudo certo, faço o redirecionamento da página da seguinte forma:

```
window.location.href = '/admin/lojas/produtos';
```

O problema é que sempre aparece o alerta abaixo e o usuário tem que ficar clicando em "sair da página" para completar o *redirect*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu sei que é normal aparecer esse alerta quando se faz o *submit* do formulário por *POST*, mas teria alguma forma de mudar a forma que estou fazendo o *redirect* para contornar esse aviso?

Comment: Cara, tem como mostrar o código? Tipo, geralmente esse alerta é ativado quando tem algo sendo processado ainda(se não me engano).

Comment: Não deveria dar esse aviso, a não ser que esteja direcionando para a mesma página. Neste caso, o navegador pode entender que o usuário pode perder os dados ao direcionar...

Answer (score 0):

Caso alguém passe pelo mesmo problema, acabei conseguindo resolver ao inserir antes do redirecionamento o seguinte código:

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```